# Save instance state - how it's works?

Tags: android

In Activity we have method

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //...
}
```

My questions is:

1) If I didn't override `onSaveInstaceState`, can `savedInstanceState` be not null?

2) If it can, is there a way to check existance of some `savedInstanceState` field better than

```
if(savedInstanceState.getString("SomeField")!=null){...}
```

3) How to handle `onSaveInstanceState` method in debugger? I testing my app on real device, that have a lot of memory (Asus TF101), so it's a problem to "overflow" it each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, it can't. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
2. Use [Bundle.containsKey](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#containsKey%28java.lang.String%29)
3. To "overflow"? What is the reason to do this?

Comment: 3. I'm waiting when OS "kill" my app to watch how its onSaveInstanceState works

Comment: `onSaveInstanceState` is called, for example, then Activity is killed due to configuration changes, such a screen orientation change. It is better test case than memory overflow.